# How to store subscribed endpoints for sending Push notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, endpoints, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on push notifications and when user subscribs to notifications,a unique endpoint is generated.
i want to know that how can i store these endpoints in db ,so that further i can use these endpoints to send notifications to all the subscribed users

Comment: What do you mean? The endpoints are URLs, you can save them in the DB as strings.

Comment: @marco endpoints are not urls.endpoints are like ----"agjdijdbdbsgh256hshdh272-73sbbshhs" ---this. These are used to send notification to particular device

Comment: No, endpoints are URLs, like `https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/SOME_UNIQUE_ID`.
The endpoint isn't `SOME_UNIQUE_ID`, but the entire URL.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted in the [official docs:](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration)

> 2. The client app passes the registration token to the app server.

Here's 2 potential ways to achieve this:

### DIY

Send the registration ID to your server directly from your app & save to a database. You can also store any other unique identifier by which you want to identify this registration (e.g. user's email) and store them together.

You can create an endpoint in your server like http://www.myserver.com/gcmregistrations and POST the registration there.

### GCM Upstream (not recommended)

If you're using GCM with an XMPP server you could send the registration ID as an upstream message in GCM.

I wouldn't recommend this as there's no way to know from your app that the data was sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
const dummyDb = { subscription: null }
const saveToDatabase = async subscription => {

    dummyDb.subscription = subscription
    console.log(dummyDb)
    //Stored in dummy memory
}
```

Now call
`saveToDatabase(----Your subscription object----)`

This will work!